# Unexpected loop in payment calculator

Tags: python-3.x, loops, calculator

I have run this code and changed it more times than I can count but it always results in a loop. I'm not quite sure what I've done wrong nor how to end the loop.
     """
    WeeklyPay.py: generate payroll stubs for all hourly paid employees and summarizes them
    """

```
 def main():
    """
total_gross_pay = 0
hours_worked = 0
gross_pay = 0
hourly_rate= 0

:return: None
"""



 employee = input("Did the employee work this week? Y or y for yes: ")
 while employee == "Y" or "y":
    hours_worked = int(input("How many hours did the employee work this week? "))
    hourly_rate = int(input("What is the employee's hourly rate? "))



 gross_pay = hours_worked * hourly_rate


 print("Your weekly pay is: "+ gross_pay)



 main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the `while` loop shown below works more like what your program should do:

```
def main():
    """Help the user calculate the weekly pay of an employee."""
    while input('Did the employee work this week? ') in {'Y', 'y'}:
        hours_worked = int(input('How many hours? '))
        hourly_rate = int(input('At what hourly rate? '))
        gross_pay = hours_worked * hourly_rate
        print('The weekly pay is:', gross_pay)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `while` loop, in which the variable `employee` is never changed, so the condition stays `True`. It should work if you replace the `while` with an `if`.

Comment: Although this answers the OP's question, it does not help them that much since the if-clause will always be executed because `employee == "Y" or "y"` will always result `True`.